# Extract Date and Message for error from a log file in Java

Tags: java

I need to extract Date and Message for those line which are having error from a log file. The pattern of date ifs yyyy-mm-dd and message is as usual string. And I need to combine all the errors for a particular day. The file size is more than 10 mb. So in a efficient way how can I do this in Java??

Comment: The most efficient I found is writing the code. Tell me if you know any other.

Answer (score 0):

It will be more efficient if you write only error logs to a seperate error log file and roll it over daily.